# Undefined when trying to use addClass on $(this) anchor tag

Tags: jquery, addclass, attr, prop

```js
function showImage(imageSrc) {
            
            $('a.slideTabLinkBlock').removeClass('active');
            alert($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).addClass('active');

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="slideTabLinkBlock" onclick="showImage('<?php echo $image_src; ?>');">Link</a>
```

I'm trying to add a class "active" when a link is clicked:

```
<a class="slideTabLinkBlock" onclick="showImage('<?php echo $image_src; ?>');"></a>

function showImage(imageSrc) {

    $('a.slideTabLinkBlock').removeClass('active');
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
    $(this).addClass('active');

}
```

When I alert $(this).attr('class') it displays "undefined".

Why am I not able to target the anchor tag with $(this)?

How can I add the "active" class to the link that is clicked?

Comment: Because you use inline event handlers (`onclick=""`)  instead of doing it properly.

Comment: Well, the link is inside a loop and I am passing the image_src variable value which I get from inside the loop

Comment: Downvote? For asking a clearly explained question.

Answer (score 0):

When using a proper event handler you can store your `$image_src` variable e.g. in a `data`-attribute.

```js
$('.slideTabLinkBlock').on('click', function() {

  var $this = $(this),
    imgSrc = $this.data('imgsrc');

  $('a.slideTabLinkBlock').removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');
   alert($(this).attr('class'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="slideTabLinkBlock" data-imgsrc="<?php echo $image_src; ?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not providing any additional code I don't know why you are using an inline function in the anchor tag.
Because you could normally do this:

```
$('a.slideTabLinkBlock').on('click',function(){
    var className =  $(this).attr('class');

    alert(className);
})
```

Answer (score -3):

`$(this)` is refering to the Window object and thus not what you expect to be.
You can pass "this" to the function inside the inline JS call, and create a jQuery element of the argument. See the snippet:

```js
function showImage(element, imageSrc) {

            $('a.slideTabLinkBlock').removeClass('active');
            alert($(element).attr('class'));
            $(element).addClass('active');

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="slideTabLinkBlock" onclick="showImage(this, '<?php echo $image_src; ?>');">Link</a>
```

Comment: Why are there downvotes on the question and on this answer? It's a clear question. And this answer is doing what @alwayslearning wants to do.